# Request with python doesn't work but postman work

Tags: python, post, header, request, postman

I work with Django (Python 3.5) and try `request.post` to one url but it returns error 405.
In postman I chose post method and in body fill my data, the header is `Content-Type :application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the result is true.

My python script is :

```
import requests as r

login_data = {
   'UserName': 'uuuuu',
   'Password': 'pppppp'
}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
a=r.post(url, data=login_data,headers=headers)
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a case you should look at your server, and printout request. I would try with:

```
import requests as r
import json 

login_data = {
    'UserName': 'uuuuu',
    'Password': 'pppppp'
}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} 
a=r.post(url, data=json.dumps(login_data), headers=headers)
```